# What should I do about this smoke detector that beeps constantly?

Tags: smoke-detectors

My smoke detector beeps constantly when connected. Looks like I need to change the battery. But I have no clue where to put in the battery or how to change. Your help will be appreciated.

The unit is on the ceiling. I just held the cover next to it for the photo.

[image: my smoke detector]

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment, so I'm posting this as an answer because this is quite important: Please make sure to be absolutly careful when handling this smoke detector! Its an old ionization-smoke detector, and it contains radioactive americium-241. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_detector#Ionization Please make sure to properly dispose the old smoke alarm.

Comment: Unless it's a very old (20+ year) smoke detector that contains more radioactive materials than more modern detectors, if not prohibited by local or state regulation, it may be disposed of in a landfill:  [These smoke detectors should be recycled if possible. (The 
Recycling Electronic Devices section of this Tech Talk provides 
information about how to recycle unneeded electronics.) 
Alternately, unless State or local regulation requires other-
wise, they may be disposed of as normal municipal waste.](https://www.usfa.fema.gov/downloads/pdf/techtalk/techtalk_v1n2_1209.pdf)

Comment: Before replacing it I'd trying blowing it out with a can of Dust-Off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doesn't look like it *has* a battery.  How old is it? There should be a manufacture or expiry date written on the cover.

Many older AC powered detectors didn't have backup batteries.  That cable you unplugged is the AC power. If it's over 10 years old (or maybe it's 5 years now) it should be replaced anyways.

Replace the smoke detector. They aren't expensive. If it is acting up you don't want to depend on it when there is a fire.

Comment: Having just replaced my detectors last year, newer detectors have a 10 year life span. I dated all of mine to ensure I knew when they were due.

Comment: @paulster2 There may be local rules limiting their lifespan to less than that regardless of what the mfg  says - my city was talking about doing that but I don't recall if they actually did.

Answer (score 2):

When the radioactive bits decay too much, they don't emit enough radiation for the detector. Because of this, the alarm will sound or chirp (by design) so that you replace the alarm.